# Modify Fibonacci Heap to Have a Linear Chain of Marked/Unmarked Nodes Only

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, heaps

In CLRS book there is an exercise (19.4-2), the aim of which is to create a linear chain of nodes by a sequence of Fibonacci-Heap operations. I have solved the problem by recursively making a union with a chain of two nodes, inserting a new minimum node and extracting the minimum, after which consolidation takes place and after deleting the node on the shortest path returns a new linear chain. Since there are no `DECREASE-KEY` or `DELETE-NODE` operations, no node is being marked.

My question is, is it possible to create a linear chain consisting of marked nodes only. If so, how?

I have tried several strategies. In one case I am getting a linear chain with all but the last node marked and I cannot proceed from there.

Another possibility is to get a chain as follows for $n$ nodes:

[image: Example of resulting FH]

From here one can delete all the nodes on the shortest path for each sub-tree starting from the bottom to mark all of the nodes on the longer path. However, I cannot find a way to get this Fibonacci-Heap in the first place (and I am not sure whether it is possible). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this is exercise 4-1 not 4-2